# How do I get every consecutive elements from a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Let say I have a list 
`[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`

I want to get every consecutive element and put it in another predicate.

```
func(a,b).
func(b,c).

func(d,e).
func(e,f).

func(g,h).
func(h,i).
```

I already wrote the predicate I want to put in, but I'm having a hard time getting two elements from the list of lists.

Comment: Just `flatten/2` list to ease taking out two cons. elements as @joel76 suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
consecutive(L, R) :-
    maplist(create_func, L, RT),
    flatten(RT, R).

create_func([A,B], [func(A,B)]) :- !.

create_func([A,B | T], [func(A,B) | R]) :-
    create_func([B | T], R).
```